# Ionic 4 - Api calls are not working when I run the app in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic4

I am facing issue while trying to login from ios. The api call is not working.Where as I am able to login from browser and android device.

From ionic cli if i use command -> ionic cordova ios -l , then I am able to log in or the api call works but if I remove the -l(livereload) that does not work from ionic cli as well.

From Xcode-: I use ionic cordova prepare ios and run from xcode and try to log in both in simulator and ios device, but api call does not work and I dont see any error in log as well.

The things I have tried so far: -

1. Added the white list options in my config.xml
2. In my info.plist I have the NSAppTransportSecurity.
3. The CORS is enabled from server side.

Please let me know how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: Same issue here, adding in consideration that I already use native HTTP plugin as recommended from some contributors. I did some extra debugging in backend, using accesslog in apache server and I notice that iOS requests use OPTIONS method instead of the normal GET/POST/PUT http methods.
Not sure what makes our 1 year old working app suddenly decides to send OPTIONS requests instead of POST! while it works perfectly in Android and browser. The HTTP client-server is being interrupted at some how from Apple and this is a serious issue!.